# Problema em chamar o DriveManager.getConnection?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Estou estudando Java com banco de dados e estou fazendo uns exemplos. No PC com **Windows** eu utilizei um código e deu certo, não ocorreu nenhum problema, agora voltei a usar **Linux** e o mesmo código está dando erro na hora de chamar o método `DriveManager.getConnection` do `JDBC`.

Segue abaixo o código.

```
package br.com.utd.jdbc;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;

public class Conexao {
    private final static String URL = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/livraria";
    private final static String USUARIO = "root";
    private final static String SENHA = "**********";

    public static Connection factoryConexao(){
        Connection conexao = null;
        try{
            conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USUARIO, SENHA);
            return conexao;
        }catch(SQLException e1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  
                       "Falha na conexão com o banco de dados:"+e1);
            return conexao;
        }
    }

}
```

O erro é o seguinte o ***Eclipse*** sugere que adicione um cast com `Connection` em:

```
conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USUARIO, SENHA);
```

não consigo entender, porque fazer um `cast` com `Connection` se ele é uma `Connection`?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Adicione o erro se possivel na pergunta. Se não for um stacktrace, adicione uma imagem mostrando a mensagem do eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> não consigo entender, porque fazer um cast com Connection se ele é uma Connection?

Isso acontece porque tem `import` errado (`import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;`) no seu código o correto seria `imports java.sql.Connection;`, os outros estão corretos.

O erro que está na imagem está dizendo tipos diferentes, e o `Eclipse` está tentando arrumar o seu código dando um `cast`, mas, o problema realmente era que o `imports` está errado para `Connection`.

Os `imports` corretos são:

```
import java.sql.Connection; 
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; // esse é o único que não faz parte do problema
```

<sub>***Referencia:***</sub>

- [Class DriverManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html)
- [Interface Connection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html)

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado.

Comment: Só uma correção, apenas o import `import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;` está incorreto, os outros estão certos.

Comment: @diegofm eu coloquei para eles todos os `imports` como deveriam ser, eu entendo que só esse está errado (`import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;`), mas, também falta outro `import` (`java.sql.Connection;`) para que o código funcione, quis resumir o problema no seu todo e mostrar para o usuário quais são as importação corretas, vou ratificar isso na resposta, mas, terei também que posicionar o que está faltando. Obrigado.

Comment: @diegofm pronto